# how to change text from a function when clicking on the dice - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I change my `<Text style={styles.advice}>` with API data from the function getUrl when I click on the dice?
Can it be because when I console log getUrl function i get a promise object. If that is the case how do I solve that?
Any advice if I could write this code any better would be appreciated!

**Boxes.js**

```
export function button() {
  async function getUrl() {
    const url = "https://api.adviceslip.com/advice";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const text = data.slip.advice;
    return text;
  }
  getUrl();
}

export default class Boxes extends react.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>{button.getUrl}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.advice}>
          It is easy to sit up and take notice, what's difficult is getting uu
          and taking action
        </Text>
        <PatternDivider />
        <Dice />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Dice.js**

```
import { button } from "./Boxes";

export default class Dice extends react.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Pressable style={styles.circle} onPress={button}>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/icon-dice.png")}
          style={styles.dice}
        />
      </Pressable>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll want to use a state variable to store whatever text is returned from the URL. Your Boxes.js would look something like this:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
const [apiText, setApiText] = useState("It is easy to sit up and take notice, what's difficult is getting up and taking action");

export function button() {
  async function getUrl() {
    const url = "https://api.adviceslip.com/advice";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const text = data.slip.advice;
    setApiText(text);
  }
  getUrl();
}

export default class Boxes extends react.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>{button.getUrl}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.advice}>
         {apiText}
        </Text>
        <PatternDivider />
        <Dice />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Your

```
<Text style={styles.advice}>
```

would initially be the text "It is easy to sit up and..." but on button press its state would be updated to the text returned from fetch(url). You can find out more about state variables here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/state

Comment: When I look into the code that you provided I get an error for invalid hook call

Comment: What specific error message are you receiving? It may be due to incorrect import statements, or the improper use of hooks within class components